# Java Client server programming

Tags: network-programming, client-server

How can the server code keep track of clients. I am unable to understand this: if a client A and client B are continuously sending request to the server, how will I know which one is client A and which one is client B ??

please help.

my server code is:-

```
while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Connecting " + count++);
                Socket client = acceptor.accept();
                System.out.println("here 1");
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Client ["+client.getInetAddress() +"] tried to connect at "
                        + new GregorianCalendar().getTime());
                logger.log(Level.INFO,
                        "Connection received from  " + client.getInetAddress()
                                + ":" + client.getLocalPort() );
                processRequest(client);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to code it.
I had faced same situation where we had client server session based on log-in.. So untill they are logged in its easy to understand.